# Write blocks in a text file to multiple new files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to extract blocks in a text file and put them to new individual files. For example, consider the following file:

```
some junk lines

ABC: this is abc text
abc block text1
abc block text2
abc block text3

I dont care about this line

Text at start of block. I dont want this line also. 
ABC: this is another abc text
abc block text5
abc block text2
abc block text3
abc block text1

some other dont care line
```

I am interested in 'ABC' blocks. Every block has "ABC:" at beginning and new line at the end. So, I want to generate abc1.txt that contains:

```
ABC: this is abc text
abc block text1
abc block text2
abc block text3
```

and abc2.txt that contains:

```
ABC: this is another abc text
abc block text5
abc block text2
abc block text3
abc block text1
```

I tried using awk to get the blocks but having hard time in matching ending new line.

One option is to write a script that loops through each and every line in the file. I believe there is a better solution. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `tried using awk` please add that code to question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one-liner should do the job:

```
awk '/^ABC/{p=1;close(fn);fn="abc"++i}!NF{p=0}p{print > fn}' file
```

With your example as input:

```
kent$  awk '/^ABC/{p=1;close(fn);fn="abc"++i}!NF{p=0}p{print > fn}' f

kent$  head abc*
==> abc1 <==
ABC: this is abc text
abc block text1
abc block text2
abc block text3

==> abc2 <==
ABC: this is another abc text
abc block text5
abc block text2
abc block text3
abc block text1
```

### Note:

- the `close(fn)` is necessary, if you have many "ABC" blocks, otherwise you got error msgs like "too many opened files"

Comment: Seriously compact solution! Even though nobody asked, I thought I'd add a more verbose [perl](https://www.perl.org/) equivalent: `perl -lane 'if (/^ABC/) {$p=1;$i++;open $f, ">", "abc".$i} if (/^$/) {$p=0;close $f} if ($p==1) {print {$f} $_}' test.txt`.

Comment: While that will produce the desired output its more complicated than necessary since awk has paragraph mode specifically to handle blocks of data separated by blank lines, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45103787/1745001.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem of blocks of text separated by blank lines is exactly what awks "paragraph mode" exists to handle and is activated by setting RS to the null string:

```
awk -v RS= '/^ABC:/{print > ("abc"++c".txt")}' file
```

The above will work if you don't have a lot of output files or if you're using GNU awk since it handles closing files for you when necessary. If you do have a lot of output files but can't get GNU awk then you just need to tweak it to:

```
awk -v RS= '/^ABC:/{close(f); f="abc"++c".txt"; print > f}' file
```

Answer (score -2):

```
awk '/^ABC:/,/^$/' filename
```

Search for all lines starting with ABC: (^ for the start of the line) to any thing with a blank line (^$) Use the , to lines to and from.

Comment: that won't separate the blocks to different files