# What is the fastest method to write blocks of data from a huge file to a new file?

Tags: python-3.x, awk, bigdata

Suppose I have a file, which is just a repetition of very similar blocks (simplified example shown below). What would be the fastest method to extract certain blocks and write them to separate files? All blocks start with the same number \n. The input file can have over a million steps and each block can be several thousands of atoms. Hence, I do not want to read in the (huge) file or fully loop over it, as I only need a limited number of steps (e.g. every 1000 steps). I am considering bash scripting (sed or head|tail with grouping), python (memory mapping and storing the blocks with regex) or awk ([Write blocks in a text file to multiple new files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098279/write-blocks-in-a-text-file-to-multiple-new-files)). Are there any methods or languages I am not aware of?
Thank you

```
6
step 1
C                  9.0000000    8.3380808    9.0000001
C                  9.0000000    9.6619194    8.9999999
H                  8.0768455    7.7678700    9.0000001
H                  9.9231545   10.2321301    9.0000001
H                  8.0768455   10.2321301    9.0000001
H                  9.9231545    7.7678700    9.0000001
6
step 2
 C                  9.00000000    8.33808080    9.00000010
 C                  9.00000000    9.66191940    8.99999990
 H                  8.07684550    7.76787000    9.00000010
 H                  9.90912982   10.23213008    8.83969637
 H                  8.09087028   10.23213012    9.16030383
 H                  9.92315450    7.76787000    9.00000010
6
step 3
 C                  9.00000000    8.33808080    9.00000010
 C                  9.00000000    9.66191940    8.99999990
 H                  8.07684550    7.76787000    9.00000010
 H                  9.86748170   10.23213006    8.68426301
 H                  8.13251850   10.23213014    9.31573717
 H                  9.92315450    7.76787000    9.00000010
```

Comment: See [mcve], your description of the task doesn't really help

Comment: If the number of bytes of each block is the same, you can `mmap` the file and compute the start and end of each block that you need. Seek there, read the exact number of bytes and repeat for each block. If the number of bytes differ... then you will have to traverse the whole file.

Comment: Maybe something with `dd` if the blocks are all the same size?

Comment: _I only need a limited number of steps_ Could you please show the expected output for the sample data presented? Also, are those `\n`s strings or newlines? In the latter case, there is no need to show them in the sample data, please edit them out.

Comment: Is the 6 the number of data lines in the following block?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small POC in [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html). Is this close to what you wanted?

```
awk '
  /^[0-9]/ { print "skipping " $0; next; }
  /step /  { fn = sprintf("%s.%s", $1, $2); print "assigned fn = ", fn; }
  /^ *[A-Z]/ { print $0 >> fn; print "sent ", $0, " to ", fn; }
' infile
```

The output:

```
skipping 6
assigned fn =  step.1
sent  C                  9.0000000    8.3380808    9.0000001  to  step.1
sent  C                  9.0000000    9.6619194    8.9999999  to  step.1
sent  H                  8.0768455    7.7678700    9.0000001  to  step.1
sent  H                  9.9231545   10.2321301    9.0000001  to  step.1
sent  H                  8.0768455   10.2321301    9.0000001  to  step.1
sent  H                  9.9231545    7.7678700    9.0000001  to  step.1
skipping 6
assigned fn =  step.2
sent   C                  9.00000000    8.33808080    9.00000010  to  step.2
sent   C                  9.00000000    9.66191940    8.99999990  to  step.2
sent   H                  8.07684550    7.76787000    9.00000010  to  step.2
sent   H                  9.90912982   10.23213008    8.83969637  to  step.2
sent   H                  8.09087028   10.23213012    9.16030383  to  step.2
sent   H                  9.92315450    7.76787000    9.00000010  to  step.2
skipping 6
assigned fn =  step.3
sent   C                  9.00000000    8.33808080    9.00000010  to  step.3
sent   C                  9.00000000    9.66191940    8.99999990  to  step.3
sent   H                  8.07684550    7.76787000    9.00000010  to  step.3
sent   H                  9.86748170   10.23213006    8.68426301  to  step.3
sent   H                  8.13251850   10.23213014    9.31573717  to  step.3
sent   H                  9.92315450    7.76787000    9.00000010  to  step.3
```

The result files:

```
$: cat step.1
C                  9.0000000    8.3380808    9.0000001
C                  9.0000000    9.6619194    8.9999999
H                  8.0768455    7.7678700    9.0000001
H                  9.9231545   10.2321301    9.0000001
H                  8.0768455   10.2321301    9.0000001
H                  9.9231545    7.7678700    9.0000001
$: cat step.2
 C                  9.00000000    8.33808080    9.00000010
 C                  9.00000000    9.66191940    8.99999990
 H                  8.07684550    7.76787000    9.00000010
 H                  9.90912982   10.23213008    8.83969637
 H                  8.09087028   10.23213012    9.16030383
 H                  9.92315450    7.76787000    9.00000010
$: cat step.3
 C                  9.00000000    8.33808080    9.00000010
 C                  9.00000000    9.66191940    8.99999990
 H                  8.07684550    7.76787000    9.00000010
 H                  9.86748170   10.23213006    8.68426301
 H                  8.13251850   10.23213014    9.31573717
 H                  9.92315450    7.76787000    9.00000010
```

Note that your example had no leading spaces on the first section, but had one on subsequent sections.

Adjust as needed, hope it helps.

Comment: This certainly solves the problem, yet doesn't answer the question *which method would be the fastest?*

Comment: Something that reads the file once and handles the task as it goes is generally going to be faster than anything which has to make several passes. Something like `awk` will be faster than a `bash` script, assuming pure `bash` using `read`. You might get faster results running several executables in parallel with a pipeline, but `head|tail` would have to be executed over and over to get all the sections, so don't do that. I see little value in memory mapping if you're just going to write to files. My answer to *which would be fastest* was implicit in my example - sorry for being unclear.